# Google ads - what does "This image doesn't meet the minimum requirements for 2 crop ratios mean" Landscape, square, and portrait

Tags: google-ads

**What is the secret of the Google Ads carousel card display aspect ratios?**

In my Google ads campaign, I have an ad that will have a carousel of cards.

each card in Google ads wants all 3 of Landscape, square, and portrait.

[image]

For my next card, I can only crop it in Square and Landscape:

[image]

Then, it prompts me to select an image for the 4:5 version, which I edit in Photoshop to exactly 400x500. theoretically should be able to specify a specifically-cropped version for this aspect ratio and upload another image, however, when I do so, this is what I get:

[image]

if I don't have all the cards match, Google ads won't allow my ad to save:

[image]

Comment: Called Google ads at 7:43 PM  last night. They claim they are open until 9 PM. waited 15 minutes through a queue to talk to a "receptionist"-- then I waited another 20 minutes while the "receptionist" wait TOO for the ad specialist queue. Finally 30 minutes later she comes back and says she'll take my number for a callback (which she says would be soon), but they do not call back before 9PM.

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer from Google ads